# Are code obfuscation techniques off topic on this site?

Tags: discussion, scope

In questions like:
[Obfuscating JavaScript code](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/35828/obfuscating-javascript-code)
are treated some aspect of obfuscation of scripting languages, but not the obfuscation techniques for themselves (es. *How can I produce obuscated code ?*).

Obviously, a lot of members of this community are highly skilled in this field; probably it's the most relevant one. Is the topic accepted here ?

Comment: If a site on SE has obfuscation expertise, it's [reverseengineering.se]. Breaking obfuscation techniques is a central topic there.

Comment: Related to [Are DRM related questions on-topic here?](http://meta.security.stackexchange.com/questions/2109/are-drm-related-questions-on-topic-here) in that both topics discuss securing intellectual property.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the details of the question, I'd say that the techniques for *how* to code something falls under a "programming" question and not a security question.

Questions dealing with the impact or efficacy of obfuscation would be on-topic here.